# What CCTV Software is available?

Tags: software-recommendation, webcam

I would like to setup Ubuntu to capture motion in my studio and e-mail pictures of anyone who enters it. MS Windows has plenty of software to do this, but now that I switched 100% to Ubuntu, I need a software to accomplish this. Ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use Zoneminder.

> ZoneMinder is intended for use in single or multi-camera video
>   security applications, including commercial or home CCTV, theft
>   prevention and child or family member or home monitoring and other
>   care scenarios.<sup>1</sup>
>
> The three main reasons for surveillance are security, safety and
>   nosiness. Whether you need a visual check on a sleeping baby, or a
>   video of a stranger putting your cat in a wheelie bin, Zoneminder fits
>   the bill. Zoneminder is a sophisticated camera manager, including
>   support for multiple image sources, motion detection, email alerts,
>   and X10 automation. It supports most V4L (Video for Linux) devices,
>   and can control network IP cameras. The web interface makes it ideal
>   for use on our headless server.<sup>2</sup>  [Read On](http://www.tuxradar.com/content/build-your-own-surveillance-zoneminder)

To install Zoneminder, just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, run the command below.

```
sudo apt-get install zoneminder
```

Or

[image]

<sup><sup>**1**</sup>Source:[Ubuntu Apps Directory](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/zoneminder/)</sup>

<sup><sup>**2**</sup>Source:[TuxRadar](http://www.tuxradar.com/content/build-your-own-surveillance-zoneminder)</sup>

Comment: Zoneminder is overly complicated.

Comment: @empedokles I think that its a matter of opinion.  My business partner uses it as his main program for his customers, and no one has complained yet.

Comment: iSpy (only windows) or Xemoa are definitely much easier to install and use. I don't consider Zoneminder professional grade software nor does anyone on cctvforums I know of. Xemoa will come closer, but it costs money from what I know for continuous use. It's a pity that there is no good cctv-software on linux.

Comment: ZoneMinder is actually not good enough for modern use. Try Shinobi http://shinobi.video/features#learn

Answer (score 4):

You can try `motion` to to do what you want. It is a command line tool that runs in the background once setup.

See http://www.unixmen.com/how-to-turn-your-webcam-into-a-motion-detecting-security-spy-camera-in-linux/ 
and http://www.chriswpage.com/2009/05/setup-an-advanced-webcam-security-system-with-ubuntu-8-04-and-motion/
for setup guides.

The basic steps are:

- Install motion: `sudo apt-get install motion`

or

[image]

- Configure motion: `sudo gedit /etc/motion/motion.conf`
- Start motion: `sudo motion`

Hope this helps

Comment: Since I can't post my answer I'll leave a comment
Try Shinobi :D
http://shinobi.video/features#learn

Answer (score -1):

I am UBUNTU user as well and I'm using Xeoma software for my CCTV system. (It is available over the Ubuntu Software-Center.)

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu. Could you provide some links to the software along with some of its features and screenshots? That would vastly improve this answer.

Comment: ShinobiCCTV : http://shinobi.video/features#learn